# tuning oracle bulk collect

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
             FORALL indx IN 1 .. l_tab.COUNT
                  
               update repair_part_bp_r5 bp
               set is_deleted='Y'           
               where 1=1
               and bp.repair_part_id = l_tab(indx)
               and bp.batch_id=p_batch_id;
```

It is waiting on latch: redo writing as the volume of update is 120011.

Would it help breaking it down into smaller chunk during the update ?

If so pls help with code sample?

any other idea ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have declared the data type of `l_tab` in SQL using `CREATE TYPE` then you do not need a loop and can use the `MEMBER OF` operator:

```sql
update repair_part_bp_r5 bp
set   is_deleted='Y'           
where bp.repair_part_id MEMBER OF l_tab
and   bp.batch_id=p_batch_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is such redo work optimization like "array update" (read more details in "Oracle Core" by Jonathan Lewis). Most probably that it doesn't work for such FORALL updates. So I'd suggest to use `MERGE` with `using (select column_value as repair_part_id from TABLE(ltab) s ON (bp.batch_id=p_batch_id and bp.repair_part_id =s.repair_part_id)` or simply

```sql
update repair_part_bp_r5 bp
set   is_deleted='Y'           
where bp.repair_part_id in (select * from table(l_tab))
and   bp.batch_id=p_batch_id;
```

nb: ltab must be a collection type defined on schema or package level.